# Why 'to bid fair' and NOT 'to bid fairness'?

Tags: grammaticality

> [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bid-fair-to): **bid fair to** {archaic or literary} = Seem likely to

Am I right that 'fair' has never been a noun meaning 'fairness'? [fair {noun}](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/fair?searchDictCode=all#fair) lists only 'A beautiful woman.' as one archaic meaning, which's noncontextual here.  If so, ought this expression be the more correct: 'bid fairness to' ? Why does this jar with use of the noun (instead) for the idiom ['bid defiance'](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bid+fair) ?

Footnote: I encountered the idiom above while reading [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_v._Lopez#Supreme_Court_decision).

Comment: Fair in this fixed expression is a (now mostly obsolete) adverb; to *bid fair to VERB* is to "offer a fair (=pleasing) prospect of VERBING". The expression might be paraphrased "promise well".

Comment: That's an answer, StoneyB. And better than the one offered by Jasper, as it has some backing.

Comment: BTW, we don't typically contract "which is" to "which's".

Comment: The heyday of "bid defiance" as an idiom was around 1800.  Your sense of the language is becoming quite distorted by this diet of legalese...like Woyzeck with the peas.

Comment: See [sense I. 4 (intransitive) **to bid fair**](https://www.oed.com/oed2/00021726). It's a fixed expression. You can't change a fixed expression.

Comment: You can't always "reason" with idioms, they have a life of their own.

Answer (score 1):

My sense of how the idiom breaks down is that bidding refers to the concept of competing options (as we see when bids are considered by those offering a contract or an item for sale), and that "fair" means "moderate" (as in "fairly likely"

So to me, one alternative way of arranging these concepts and usages would be 
"... offers a fair chance of ..."

for instance 
"the team bids fair to rise to the top of the rankings"

could be restated
"the team offers a fair chance of rising to the top of the rankings"

Answer (score -2):

When I hear the phrase "bid fair to", I think of "sunny skies and fair weather".  In other words, a beautiful day without storms, gusts, disabling calm, or other natural hindrances.

On such a day, if I set out to do something that can reasonably be done in a day, I am likely to be able to do it.  The weather won't be a problem.